# iframe height wont decrease but increases

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a simple index.html file which is included in an iframe. I want the height of the iframe being adapted by the content which is being displayed.

In my example the iframe size will increase when the button is being clicked but it won't decrease anymore.... you can even change the width of the window and you can see that the document.body.scrollHeight will only increase but not decrease when being strechted...

What am I missing here?

This is how my index.html file looks like

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100vw;
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .test,
        .cop {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .test {
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .cop {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const btn = document.querySelector('button')
            const cop = document.querySelector('.cop')

            btn.onclick = () => {
                btn.classList.toggle('open')
                btn.innerHTML = btn.classList.contains('open') ? 'close' : 'open'
                btn.classList.contains('open') ? cop.classList.remove('hidden') : cop.classList.add('hidden')
                iframeResize()
            }
        })

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => iframeResize())

        function iframeResize() {
            let message = { height: document.body.scrollHeight }
            window.top.postMessage(message, "*")
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="test">open</button>
    <div class="cop card hidden" style="border: solid black; height: 2000px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is how my iframe.html file looks like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iframe test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: blueviolet;
            margin: auto;
        }

        iframe {
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        .content {
            margin: 10% 0;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var src = 'index.html';
        var params = window.location.search ? window.location.search : '';
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('src', src + params);
        iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
        iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);

        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            document.querySelector('.iframe').appendChild(iframe);
        });

        window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
            console.log(e.data.height)
            if (e.data.height) iframe.style.height = e.data.height + 'px';
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content above">content-above</div>
    <div class="iframe"></div>
    <div class="content below">content-below</div>
</body>

</html>
```